# How to populate a json object from javascript to Spring Rest Post

Tags: javascript, json, spring, rest, post

I'm trying to send a json object built with javascript to back end...I'm using Spring 4 with the REST web service that fill an object with the post call.
I checked the http call I'm getting the status 200, but the object on the back end is empty.

**This is the ajax call**

```
function buildObject() {

var obj = {
    'Title' : 'a',
    'SubTitle' : 'b',
    'Paragraph' : 'c'
};

console.log(obj);

$.ajax({
    url : 'chargeDB',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(obj)
}).done(function(response, textStatus) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(textStatus);
});
```

}

**This is my back-end**

```
@Controller
public class DispatcherWeb {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceInt service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/chargeDB", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody EsempioModel chargeDB(@RequestBody EsempioModel obj) {
        System.out.println(obj.getTitle1());
        service.saveNewspaper(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

**This is my Object**

```
public class EsempioModel {

private String title1;
private String subtitle1;
private String paragraph1;

public String getTitle1() {
    return title1;
}
public void setTitle1(String title1) {
    this.title1 = title1;
}
public String getSubtitle1() {
    return subtitle1;
}
public void setSubtitle1(String subtitle1) {
    this.subtitle1 = subtitle1;
}
public String getParagraph1() {
    return paragraph1;
}
public void setParagraph1(String paragraph1) {
    this.paragraph1 = paragraph1;
}
```

}

**This is my configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "spring.controller" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("**.css").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(86400);
        registry.addResourceHandler("**.html").addResourceLocations("/html/").setCachePeriod(86400);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/").setCachePeriod(86400);
        registry.addResourceHandler("**.js").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(86400);
    }

}
```

**This is my build.gradle**

```
    dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.8'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.jackson', name: 'jackson-mapper-asl', version: '1.5.0' 
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'eclipselink', version: '2.6.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.11.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.1-901-1.jdbc4'
}
```

**This is the Chrome Network:**

```
    Request URL:http://localhost:8080/chargeDB
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 03 Sep 2017 15:25:26 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:42
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:_ga=GA1.1.317826645.1502877286
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Mobile Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
view source
{Title: "a", SubTitle: "b", Paragraph: "c"}
Paragraph
:
"c"
SubTitle
:
"b"
Title
:
"a"
```

Thanks for you help !

Comment: since your `dataType` is json, did you just try `data : obj`, without JSON.stringify.?

Comment: Hi, So I tried, I deleted the dataType attribute and I got always the empty object, instead deleting JSON.stringify I got error 400

Comment: why do your fields have 1 at the end of each of them?

Comment: Because I have other objects with the same structure; that is only a manner to recognize each other. I have an other title2, title3 etc.

Comment: I dont understand why having other objects with a similar structure requires you to have title1, title2, title3 but regardless default model binding wont work in this instance as Spring default will do model binding based on field name. You're sending title but that doesn't exist on your object

Comment: Thank you !!! I changed the name of the objects... and work fine !!